# How to check which version of v8 is installed with my NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, v8

How is V8 installed along with NodeJs? What version is my current V8 engine?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**Easy way:**
Type in command line: `node -p process.versions.v8`

**Hard way:**

1. Type `node --version` to get the Node.js version.
2. Go to the [Node.js Changelogs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/doc/changelogs).
3. Find and open an appropriate Node.js version change log.
4. Look for notes containing `V8 to`.

Comment: or, you could just ask node which version is installed via process.versions.  A little bit easier than hunting through the change log.

`node -e 'console.log(process.versions.v8);'`

Comment: when I type in "node --version" I don't get an error but I also don't get any information... just shows the prompt again. Any idea why?

Comment: The link is no longer updated, and as Ben Taber pointed out years ago, thankfully [there's a much more direct, straightforward way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6655138/157247).

Comment: This answer is good, but [@Peter Dotchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213980/114558) is more useful

Answer (score 309):

One-line solution:
`node -p process.versions.v8`

Alternative solution:
`node -e "console.log(process.versions.v8)"`

Comment: Agreed. This is also the only answer which works in Windows. All the single quote answers do nothing strangely...

Comment: ```node -p process.versions.v8``` is a bit shorter. Not that it matters, but maybe someone cares.

Comment: This answer is good, but [@Peter Dotchev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28213980/114558) is more useful

Answer (score 71):

Just run `npm version` (don't know since when this is available)

```
> npm version
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.35',
  v8: '3.14.5.9',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.30',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1j',
  npm: '1.4.28',
  xsjs: '0.1.5' }
```

Comment: Best answer to know. Also, NPM's CLI is a whackadoo-- if you add an argument onto this, it will increment the version in your package.json file, make and tag a git commit. Utterly bizarre UX, but this is useful.

Comment: yours is the best answer of this question... Unfortunately I can only vote once.. Thanks

Comment: Best answer of the bunch since it teaches a method that can be repeated for other packages.

Answer (score 32):

To check your version, check the value in `process.versions` in the REPL.

```
node -e "console.log(process.versions.v8);"
```

Additionally, you can compile node with other versions of V8 if you desire.  Obviously results may vary widely here depending on what versions you choose.

```
cd node-v0.x.x
rm -rf deps/v8
git clone http://github.com/v8/v8.git deps/v8

./configure
make
make install
```

Comment: +1, I had to use `node -e console.log(process.versions.v8)` though; nothing was being outputted otherwise.

Comment: Looks like that changed in node at some point, thanks for the tip. Edited the response to reflect that.

Answer (score 14):

You can just type:

`node -p process.versions.v8`

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun, if you have curl available in your terminal, the following should give you v8's version:

```
V=`cat /usr/include/node/node_version.h | grep -E '^\#define NODE_(MAJOR|MINOR|PATCH)_VERSION' | sed -e 's/^[^0-9]*//'`; V=`echo $V | sed -e 's/ /\./g'`; URL=https://github.com/joyent/node/raw/v$V/ChangeLog; curl --silent $URL | grep 'Upgrade v8' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^.* //'; unset V; unset URL
```

For example, in my box with node.js 0.4.7 I get:

```
3.1.8.10
```

:)

Comment: Interesting how the definition of fun can vary from an individual to another :)

Answer (score 9):

find the installed v8 version with node.

```
$ node
> process.versions.v8
'5.1.281.83'
>
```

where The **process** object is a global that provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process.

if you just type process in node repl, you see information about node(i.e. node version,v8 version,platform,env variables info etc.)

Answer (score 9):

If you're on Node.js version 7.7.3 or similar the command is

```
$ node -p "process.versions"
```

But those above work fine too.

Answer (score 8):

```
node -pe 'this.process.versions'     # all versions
node -pe 'this.process.versions.v8'  # v8 version
```

Comment: A good answer will always have an explanation of what is being done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Downvoting, because it adds nothing important to the most upvoted answer in this questions, which was posted 3 years ago.

Comment: How is this not adding anything important? It adds the correct, suggested by node, way to find out which version is used. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#how-do-i-find-which-version-of-v8-ships-with-a-particular-version-of-node-js

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are great for checking your current version. There's also a table with all Node.js versions here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/. Excerpt for example:

```
Version             Date        V8          npm     NODE_MODULE_VERSION
Node.js 11.0.0      2018-10-23  7.0.276.28  6.4.1   67
Node.js 10.13.0     2018-10-30  6.8.275.32  6.4.1   64
Node.js 10.12.0     2018-10-10  6.8.275.32  6.4.1   64
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

```
C:\Users\Liu.D.H>C:\Users\Liu.D.H\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.14.2\node -p process.versions
{
  node: '16.14.2',
  v8: '9.4.146.24-node.20',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '93',
  nghttp2: '1.45.1',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '1.1.1n+quic',
  cldr: '40.0',
  icu: '70.1',
  tz: '2021a3',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}

C:\Users\Liu.D.H>nvm use 18.0.0
Now using node v18.0.0 (64-bit)

C:\Users\Liu.D.H>node -p process.versions
{
  node: '18.0.0',
  v8: '10.1.124.8-node.13',
  uv: '1.43.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  ares: '1.18.1',
  modules: '108',
  nghttp2: '1.47.0',
  napi: '8',
  llhttp: '6.0.4',
  openssl: '3.0.2+quic',
  cldr: '41.0',
  icu: '71.1',
  tz: '2022a',
  unicode: '14.0',
  ngtcp2: '0.1.0-DEV',
  nghttp3: '0.1.0-DEV'
}

C:\Users\Liu.D.H>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also checking any nodejs v8 version using docker, like node `10.7.0` :

`docker run --rm -it node:10.7.0 bash -c "node -p process.versions"`

Answer (score 0):

v8 is bundled with Node.js. You can see what version of v8 any version of Node.js is using and when it went into production by viewing the v8 `ChangeLog` from the `node` repository. This is current master (if building from source):
 https://github.com/nodejs/node/commits/master/deps/v8/ChangeLog

To view for a specific version of Node.js, switch the branch to that version and check the `ChangeLog`s file history.

[image: Node.js change log history]