# Are jsPerf.com Chrome results reliable for node.js Benchmark?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance-testing

I was wondering what you would think about using [jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/) Chrome test results as a benchmark for node.js performance since they are both using V8 engine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com) instead. It's what powers jsPerf and works in Node.js as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to consider the different versions of v8, which are used by chrome/ium and node.js.

1. Get the version of v8 of your *current node installation*:
   `npm --versions` list the versions of the node ecosystem, include the version of v8:

   > weemonger@awesomeLinuxDistro:~$ npm --versions
   >   { npm: '2.11.3',
   >   http_parser: '2.3',
   >   modules: '14',
   >   node: '0.12.7',
   >   openssl: '1.0.1p',
   >   uv: '1.6.1',
   >   **v8: '3.28.71.19'**,
   >   zlib: '1.2.8' }
2. Get version of v8 in your current chrome/chromium:
   Type `chrome://version/` in your address bar:

   > *Chromium:*        38.0.2092.0 (Entwickler-Build 282911)
   >   *Betriebssystem:*   Windows   *(not so awesome OS)*
   >   *Blink:*            537.36 (@178012)
   >   ***JavaScript:      V8 3.28.21***
   >   *Flash:*            20,0,0,235
   >   *User-Agent:*   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2092.0 Safari/537.36
   >   ...

Kudos to [bentinata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1642665/bentinata) for the comment.

---

**But the safer approach is to benchmark in your specific environment (see [John-David Daltons answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9302312/3346021)).**

---

*Not so nice (old) ways to get the version of v8*

- node.js

  > node -e "console.log(process.versions.v8)"
  >   (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10264593/3346021)
- chrome / chromium
  See [Ariya Hidayats Blog](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/02/find-v8-version-of-certain-chrome-release.html) to determine the version of v8 used by chrome/ium.

  > First, look at the releases branches of Chromium Subversion repository, conveniently browseable at [src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/releases](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/releases).
  >   Now it’s a matter of checking the right version. At the moment of this writing, my Google Chrome says its at version 17.0.963.46.
  >   When viewing the file 17.0.963.46/DEPS (used by Gyp, the build system), you’ll find the link to the right version of V8, i.e. v8.googlecode.com/svn/branches/3.7 revision 10521.
  >  This can be cross-referenced in V8 repository: branches/3.7&start=10521.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a tool that helps me to fetch and run tests from jsperf.com: https://github.com/OrKoN/jsperf

For example:

```
jsperf get replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall 67
jsperf run replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall 67
```

67 is the revision number here. The result is like this:

[image]

Comment: Just for the record: replace method with a string will only replace the *first* occurrence of the string, while using a regex with a 'g' flag will replace *all* occurrences of the symbol(s). Using split(' ').join('') will, again, only match singular spaces, while /\s+/g will match both singular and repeating spaces.